# Splashscreen doesn't show up in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, splash-screen

The splashscreen doesn't show on my app when doing `ionic run android -lcs`.

The splashscreen plugin is installed. I've run `ionic resources` successfully.

The app launch with a black screen instead of the splash.

Typing `navigator.splashscreen.show()` in the console doesn't work.

```
$ cordova --version
6.5.0
$ ionic --version
2.2.1
```

Config.xml:

```
   <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash"/>
   <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
   <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
   <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
   <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="250"/>

<platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.2"/>
```

ionic version:

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Answer (score -1):

Bug!

When I replace

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash"/>
```

by

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash"/>
```

it seems to work...

Comment: The two look the same...?